# Submenus in menu, below them (not on the left) in twitter bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I would to know if it's easy to change the submenu in the nav-bar. I want to insert them **below** the menu of each item (**and not on the left**). Like this :

```
Menu1
-submenu1-1
-submenu-12 
Menu2
-submenu2-1
Menu3
-submenu3-1
-submen3-2
```

And so, the click on the menu have no action, cause the submenu are available below. I use the bootstrap theme in WP.

Comment: have you read the bootstrap documentation? http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar and http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns

Comment: Yes, I've read the documentation, but with the WP theme, it's not exactly the same...